# ASP.NET Ignore completely from JSON SerializerSettings

Tags: json, asp.net-core, lowercase

When I send JSON from the server with uppercase letters, the client receives it as a camel case, I want to completely undo this conversion.

I added in startup.cs

```
services.AddMvc () .AdJsonOptions (options => {
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultNamingStrategy ();
});
```

But it returned an error:

```
Error CS0266 Can not implicitly convert type 
'Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultNamingStrategy' to 
'Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.IContractResolver'. An explicit conversion 
exists
(are you missing a cast?)
```

Is it possible to send the JSON exactly as it is in a database?

I would greatly appreciate any help

Comment: How did you send the json? If you use like `public IActionResult Json() {   return Ok(new {  Id = 1,  Name = "Jack"   });   }`, it will return `{"Id":1,"Name":"Jack"}`

Answer (score 1):

Use `DefaultContractResolver` like:

```
.AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
})
```

you cannot do something like you asked for:

> Is it possible to send the JSON exactly as it is in a database?

no! because you have to tell your serializer what to do.

Imagine your column names in your database would differ e.g. `CustomerName` (capital C) and `clientName` (lowerCase c) what should your serializer to?

If it should do "nothing" you would have to write your own converter implementing `JsonConverter`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but also it sends to camelcase. I do not know what you mean `what should your serializer to? ` Nothing! I do not want a serializer at all.

Comment: if you have no serializer you would manually create a Json object. I was assuming that this is *not* what you want. When you pass a model a serializer is always invoked.